# How to subtracts values between from different dates in SQL?

Tags: sql, max, min

Let's say that I'm using the following SQL table called TestTable:

```
Date       Value1      Value2     Value3 ... Name
2013/01/01    1           4         7        Name1
2013/01/14    6           10        8        Name1
2013/02/23    10          32        9        Name1
```

And I'd like to get the increment of the values between to dates, like:

```
Value1Inc  Value2Inc Value3Inc Name
4          22        1         Name1
```

between `2013/02/23` and `2013/01/14`.

Please note that the values always increment. I'm trying the following approach found in StackOverflow:

```
select (
(select value1 from TestTable where date < '2013/01/14') -
(select value1 from TestTable where date < '2013/02/23')
) as Value1Inc,

(select value2 from TestTable where date < '2013/01/14') -
(select value2 from TestTable where date < '2013/02/23')
as Value2Inc
...
```

and so on, but this approach gives me a huge query.

I'd like to use MAX & MIN SQL functions in order to simplify the query, but I don't know exaclty how to do, as I'm not a SQL maste (at least yet:-).

Could you please guys give me a hand here?

Edit: Ups, I think that I have found the solution by myselft by adding a "GROUP BY Name" at the end of the query like this:

select name,max(value1) - min(value1) from TestTable where date < '2013-02-23' and date > '2013-01-01' GROUP BY Name

That was it!

Comment: Show us your tries so we'll be able to tell you where is your mistake.

Comment: I've tried so far the following SQL query: select name,max(value1) - min(value1) from TestTable where date < '2013-02-23' and date > '2013-01-01' and I get "Column TestTable.name is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @user1108105 : As I understood your issue is to retreive one line, say difference of values between two dates. But the querry you used retireive multirows as a result. 

What you want to have and how you did it (so we may help you).

Comment: @user1108105 : Uou can't use Aggregate functions with the name column. MIN and MAX are aggregation functions, you may use MIN(A) - MAX(B) but c'ant mix with other columns out of Group By Clause.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match the next record, using a join.  Probably the easiest way is to enumerate and join:

```
with tt as (
      select tt.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by date) as seqnum
      from testtable tt
     )
select tt.name, tt.date, ttnext.date as nextdate,
       (ttnext.value1 - tt.value1) as Diff_Value1,
       (ttnext.value2 - tt.value2) as Diff_Value2,
       (ttnext.value3 - tt.value3) as Diff_Value2
from tt left outer join
     tt ttnext
     on tt.seqnum = ttnext.seqnum - 1;
```

If your database does not support `row_number()`, you can do something similar with correlated subqueries.